# How to stop infinite loop program after compilation

Tags: c++

I am using **turbo c++** , in college we were learning loop structure and were implementing it. But when I wrote while loop it shows the result infinite times and the turbo program get hanged . Is there any way to stop this program and re-compile the code after correction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press **CTRL+ALT+Delete** from keyboard or Open Task Manager

- In the process tab check the name of your Program , it will be something like "yourProgramName.exe"
- Select that and click End Process.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your debugger doesn't let you stop the process execution, you kill the process manually, in Unix using the kill command and in Windows using the task manager, then you make your changes, compile, and try again.